# Split the list into columns using jquery or php

Tags: php

I make it `li` on for loop  Now it appear 20 li at narrow order.

```
<ul>
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++) { ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $i;?>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

I want to split it into columns like 5 list in every column

```
1   6   11   16
2   7   12   17
3   8   13   18
4   9   14   19
5   10  15   20
```

How can I do this to split. Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you could do it with a single list. You could create a new `<ul>` for each chunk though:

```
$data = range(1, 20);
$lists = array_chunk($data, 5);

foreach ($lists as $list) {
  echo '<ul>';
  echo '<li>' . implode('</li><li>', $list) . '</li>';
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

Then just float the `<ul>` elements:

```
ul {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: You could do it with one LI; just give the 6th element a class of clear-left

Answer (score 1):

I assume detecting the fifth element would be the problem?

```
<ul>
   <?php for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++) { ?>
       <li>
           <?php echo $i;?>
       </li>
  <?php
if($i % 5 == 0)
{echo "This is the end of the row";} 
} ?>
```

You can then use CSS for your formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the modulus for `$i % 5`; if it is zero, end the current list and open a new one:

```
echo '<ul>';
for( $i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++ )
{
    echo '<li>';
    echo $i;
    echo '</li>';
    if( $i % 5 == 0 )
    {
        echo '</ul><ul>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Then style your lists to get floated side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
<?php for($i=1;$i<=20;$i+=5) { ?>
    <tr>
    <?php for($j=0;$j<5;$j++) { ?>
        <td>
            <?php echo $i+$j;?>
        </td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here my sample code. But your way request is not valid for ul tag

```
<?php 

for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++) { ?>
    <?php if($i==1) { ?>
    <ul style="float:left">
    <?php } ?>      

    <li>
        <?php echo $i;?>
    </li>

    <?php if($i%5 == 0) { ?>
    </ul>
    <?php if($i != 20)  {?>
        <ul style="float:left">
    <?php } ?>      

    <?php } ?>      
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using pure css only,
set a fixed width say 450 for the parent for the ul then give each li a width of 100px and a float left
you can see a sample in the jquery ui page ,
see the link http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

```
<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">

<li class="ui-state-default">2</li><li class="ui-state-default" style="">1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
</ul>
```

Then see the styles,

```
#sortable {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 496px;
}
#sortable li {
margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
padding: 1px;
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 90px;
font-size: 4em;
text-align: center;
}
```